# Deis not creating a build when pushing application

Tags: docker, devops, deis

I am trying to push up a Node app using Deis (which has worked for months for me with this application but just recently stopped working) on AWS. I notice now that when I push up my application, a new release is not created; however, if I change a environment variable using deis config:set then a new release is created; however, it doesn't have an associated build with it (I get the following error: 'No build associated with this release' when trying to scale a process).

When pushing the application, everything seems to go well and I see:

```
Trigger 0, RUN mkdir -p /app
Step 0 : RUN mkdir -p /app
 ---> Using cache
Trigger 1, WORKDIR /app
Step 0 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
Trigger 2, ADD slug.tgz /app
Step 0 : ADD slug.tgz /app
 ---> 27a0d5cb7ff0
Removing intermediate container e4345a7b152a
Step 1 : ENV GIT_SHA f959d84d4496c48e39b045d727527d203d4e17a3
 ---> Running in 32ed021a1456
 ---> 03e742bd6cf4
Removing intermediate container 32ed021a1456
Successfully built 03e742bd6cf4
-----> Pushing image to private registry
```

When looking at the logs of the registry (which seems to be causing the problem), I see:

```
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/app/bin/create_bucket", line 23, in <module>
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: if name not in (bucket.name for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets()):
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 436, in get_all_buckets
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: response = self.make_request('GET', headers=headers)
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: retry_handler=retry_handler
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1068, in make_request
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: retry_handler=retry_handler)
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: response = connection.getresponse()
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in getresponse
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: response.begin()
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: version, status, reason = self._read_status()
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
Nov 25 05:12:43 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[12257]: socket.timeout: timed out
Nov 25 05:12:44 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 25 05:12:44 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal docker[17529]: Error response from daemon: no such id: deis-registry
Nov 25 05:12:44 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal docker[17529]: Error: failed to stop containers: [deis-registry]
Nov 25 05:12:44 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 25 05:12:44 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 25 05:12:49 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 25 05:12:49 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting deis-registry...
Nov 25 05:12:49 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal etcdctl[17601]: Error:  105: Key already exists (/deis/cache) [18268602]
Nov 25 05:12:49 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started deis-registry.
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/app/bin/create_bucket", line 23, in <module>
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: if name not in (bucket.name for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets()):
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 436, in get_all_buckets
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: response = self.make_request('GET', headers=headers)
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: retry_handler=retry_handler
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1068, in make_request
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: retry_handler=retry_handler)
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: response = connection.getresponse()
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in getresponse
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: response.begin()
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: version, status, reason = self._read_status()
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[17637]: socket.timeout: timed out
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal docker[22783]: Error response from daemon: no such id: deis-registry
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal docker[22783]: Error: failed to stop containers: [deis-registry]
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 25 05:21:55 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 25 05:22:00 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: deis-registry@1.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 25 05:22:00 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting deis-registry...
Nov 25 05:22:00 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal etcdctl[22865]: Error:  105: Key already exists (/deis/cache) [18274121]
Nov 25 05:22:00 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started deis-registry.
```

When looking at the builder, it seems to also work as it says that it is deployed:

```
Nov 25 05:39:27 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[3142]: Waiting for git-receive to run.
Nov 25 05:39:27 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[3142]: Waiting for deploy.
Nov 25 05:40:17 ip-10-0-10-252.ec2.internal sh[3142]: [info] Deploy complete.
```

(Note: the timestamps are different on the example above as I added this in a little later on a different attempt to push)

Finally, when I run deisctl list, everything shows up as active and running so it doesn't look like there are any issues there.

It seems that a lot of people online are having this issue but I haven't seen a clear response on something that works to fix this.

I have tried restarting the registry as well as destroying the entire application and relaunching it.

If it helps in terms of context, this issue started happening when I noticed that my /var/lib/docker was at 99% usage - I cleaned up images as instructed by the Deis documentation so I am now at 60% usage; however, I am still having the exact same issue.

Thanks!